# Firebase Cloud Messaging: how to send data message to all users?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I would like to send **data** messages to **all** users.

Is it possible to do it programmatically, without using the *Firebase Notifications Console*?

The problem with the Console is that the "message text" field at the beginning of the form is compulsory. So, even if I add the custom data key/values, there will also be the standard notification component.

As stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages), when the message includes both notification and data, in case the app is in the background, a standard notification message will be notified to the system tray.

I would like instead to deliver only a notification based on the custom data (trigged by `OnMessageReceived`).

How can I achieve that? Programmatically, I can correctly send data messages to specific users, but I cannot find a way to send data messages to ALL users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).  You can define the name of a topic that all installations of your app will subscribe to, then send the message to that topic.

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) from your server to send that message.  Or you can use the [FCM HTTP API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to send that message.