# How to send push notification to all the users via firebase cloud functions?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Previously I send the push notification using FCM token of the devices for particular user using `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)`.
Now I'm trying to send the push notification to all the users. But it's not working. Here is my implementation. Is this correct? If wrong how to achieve my task?

```
    const payload = {
                    notification: {
                      title: 'Hey! ',
                      body: `Check Choice of the day.`,
                      sound: 'default',
                      icon: '',
                      type: 'Editorial',
                      badge : '1'
                    }
                  };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("News",payload)
        .then(function(response){
             console.log('Notification sent successfully:',response);
        }) 
        .catch(function(error){
             console.log('Notification sent failed:',error);
        });
```

Comment: This code sends a notification to the `News` topic. App instance can only receive this, if they are subscribed to the `News` topic.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can't we send the notifications without using topic for all users?

Comment: There is no built-in way to send to all users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772167/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-message-to-all-users, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013491/firebase-cloud-messaging-how-to-send-data-message-to-all-users